# Prevent NSToolbarItem from being removed

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, appkit

I want to prevent certain toolbar items from being removed by the user. They should still be movable, just not **re**movable.

I tried creating a custom subclass of `NSToolbar` with a custom `removeItem(at:)` implementation, but it seems this method is not even called if the user drags an item out of the toolbar in the customization palette.

The delegate also doesn't seem to expose functionality for this.

How can I disable removal of certain `NSToolbarItem`s?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you can prevent it from being removed but you can implement the optional toolbarDidRemoveItem method and insert the item that you don't want it to be removed back:

```
import Cocoa

class WindowController: NSWindowController, NSToolbarDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var toolbar: Toolbar!
    override func windowDidLoad() {
        super.windowDidLoad()
        toolbar.delegate = self
    }
    func toolbarDidRemoveItem(_ notification: Notification) {
        if let itemIdentifier = (notification.userInfo?["item"] as? NSToolbarItem)?.itemIdentifier,
           itemIdentifier.rawValue == "NSToolbarShowColorsItem" {
            toolbar.insertItem(withItemIdentifier: itemIdentifier, at: 0)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems plausible, unfortunately it would not preserve the current item location.

Comment: @ErikAigner I will try to figure out if there is a way to remember its last position

Answer (score 0):

Since it is not super critical if they are removed in case a private API call would stop working, I opted for the private API solution.

```
extension NSToolbarItem {

    func setIsUserRemovable(_ flag: Bool) {
        let selector = Selector(("_setIsUserRemovable:"))
        if responds(to: selector) {
            perform(selector, with: flag)
        }
    }
}
```

This works exactly as advertised.

Answer (score 0):

When using macOS 13 or newer, there is an official way to prevent removal of certain toolbar items, by implementing function `toolbarImmovableItemIdentifiers` of `NSToolbarDelegate`, like this:

```
func toolbarImmovableItemIdentifiers(_ toolbar: NSToolbar) -> Set<NSToolbarItem.Identifier> {
    return [.toggleSidebar, .toggleInspector]
}
```